# Adjusting QML Image display size

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a QML window with a nested `RowLayout`. In the inner row I have two images. The source `.png` files for these images are (intentionally) rather large. When I attempt to set the `height` property on these images to make them smaller, they are still drawn large.

**Desired Appearance**:
[image: Two images side-by-side, taking up 1/3 of the window height]

**Actual Appearance**:
[image: Two images side-by-side, far larger than their desired size]

The only way I have been able to get them to be small is to set the `sourceSize.height:100` instead of `height:100`; however, this is not what I want. I want them to be able to scale up and down without reloading.

How can I fix my QML so that the images take on the height of their containing `RowLayout`?

```qml
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
  width:600; height:300
  visible:true

  Rectangle {
    color:'red'
    anchors { top:header.bottom; bottom:footer.top; left:parent.left; right:parent.right }
  }

  header:RowLayout {
    id:header
    spacing:0
    height:100; width:parent.width

    RowLayout {
      id:playcontrol
      Layout.minimumWidth:200; Layout.maximumWidth:200; Layout.preferredWidth:200
      height:parent.height
      Image {
        // I really want these to take on the height of their row
        source:'qrc:/img/play.png'
        width:100; height:100
        fillMode:Image.PreserveAspectFit; clip:true
      }
      Image {
        source:'qrc:/img/skip.png'
        width:100; height:100
        fillMode:Image.PreserveAspectFit; clip:true
      }
    }

    Rectangle {
      color:'#80CC00CC'
      Layout.minimumWidth:200
      Layout.preferredWidth:parent.width*0.7
      Layout.fillWidth:true; Layout.fillHeight:true
      height:parent.height
    }
  }

  footer:Rectangle { height:100; color:'blue' }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When using layouts, never specify the `width` or `height` of the item; use the `Layout` attached properties instead. The layout itself will set the `width` and `height`, effectively overriding whatever you set.

So, for your images, replace

```
width:100; height:100
```

with

```
Layout.preferredWidth: 100
Layout.preferredHeight: 100
```

This is documented [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicklayouts-overview.html#specifying-preferred-size). Specifically, the `width` and `height` are only used as a "final fallback", and they won't behave as you'd expect.

There are other places in your code where this occurs:

- `playcontrol` sets `height: parent.height` (filling the width and height of the parent is the [default behaviour for layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#fillWidth-attached-prop), so this shouldn't be necessary anyway).
- The `Rectangle` within the `playcontrol` layout also sets `height: parent.height`.

Comment: Hi, There's a *.png* image in my QML program that I want to using `Layout.preferredWidth` and `Layout.preferredHeight` reduce its size when it's loaded in the program. But these features don't have any effect on its size! Why, please?