# QML: Problems with setting the size of the button in a layout

Tags: qt, button, qml

I have this app page in qml:

```
Image {
    source: "file:///C:/Users/image.jpg"
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width/3
        height: parent.height/3
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        radius: 5

        ColumnLayout {
            width: parent.width * 0.5
            height: parent.height * 0.5
            anchors.centerIn: parent

            //some components here ...

            Button {
                //width: 100   nothing changes in the app
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom

                style: ButtonStyle {
                    background: Rectangle {
                        color: "blue"
                        radius: 15
                        //width: 100   nothing changes in the app
                    }
                    label: Text {
                        text: qsTr("Button")
                        color: "white"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to set the size (width and height) of the button, so that depends on the size of the parent (layout), something like `width: parent * 0.4`. I probably tried every possible position of the width statement in the code, but when I run the app the size of the button never changes. I also tried to set the size to a specific number, not to bind it to the parent, still nothing.

So what could be the problem here? Where and how should be the button size defined so it's binded to its parent layout size?

Comment: Replace `width: 100` with `Layout.preferredWidth: 100`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjusting QML Image display size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986928/adjusting-qml-image-display-size)

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried the suggestion from @folibis? I'm guessing this is a similar issue to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986928/adjusting-qml-image-display-size).  In that example, elements inside of a Layout were not responding to the `width` and `height` parameters.  Setting `Layout.preferredWidth` and `Layout.preferredHeight` seemed to solve the issue. Please refer to the documentation provided in that answer.

You can still bind to the parent's properties, for example

```
Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width * 0.4
```

Comment: Instead of repeating content of that answer in a new answer, you can just use flags as _duplicate_.